# C++, passing filename in string to class function using it for ifstream object

Tags: c++, string, ifstream, member

I am a C++ newbie and do not understand why my very simple code does not compile. I am trying to instantiate an ifstream object in my class by passing in a string from first argument to the app.
Building gives: **error: no match for call to '(std::ifstream) (const char*)'**

Header:

```
#ifndef _SIMPLE_TEST
#define _SIMPLE_TEST

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

class mytest {
public:
    mytest(int number);
    bool validate_config(const std::string &s);
private:
    std::ifstream configFileStream;
    int magic;
};

#endif
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include "simple.hpp"


mytest::mytest(int number) {
    magic = number;
}

bool mytest::validate_config(const std::string &s) {
    configFileStream(s.c_str());
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    bool check;
    std::string configFile(argv[1]);
    mytest DBG(17);
    check = DBG.validate_config(configFile.c_str());
    if (check) {
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Build error (from console):

```
Compile src/simple.cpp
src/simple.cpp: In member function 'bool mytest::validate_config(std::string)':
src/simple.cpp:12:28: error: no match for call to '(std::ifstream) (const char*)'
Makefile:23: recipe for target `_out/simple.o' failed
make: *** [_out/simple.o] Error 1
```

I have searched and the outcome has always bee that it should work since
I am passing the output from string class c_str() method to the mytest validate_config method (sorry for bad format of the console output)

Comment: The [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) class doesn't have an `operator()` function, which you are trying to call. Are you perhaps looking for the [`open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open) function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you're using inside `mytest::validate_config` is not doing what you expect.

```
configFileStream(s.c_str());
// tries to call 
// `std::ifstream::operator()(const char*)`
// which does not exist
```

Check out [`ifstream` on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) to verify that there's no call operator.

---

If you want to replace the existing `ifstream` instance with a new one, you have to call its constructor:

```
configFileStream = std::ifstream(s.c_str());
// creates a temporary `ifstream` from `s.c_str()`
// and assigns it to `configFileStream`
```

The above line of code is calling [`ifstream::ifstream` constructor (2)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) and then [`ifstream::operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/operator%3D).

Assigning a temporary `ifstream` to an existing one is only supported since C++11.

---

A more straightforward way of achieving what you desire is using the [`ifstream::open` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open):

```
configFileStream.open(s.c_str());
```

This approach does not create any temporary object.

Comment: Thanks, I new it was easy.

Answer (score 2):

`std::ifstream` doesn't have an `operator () (...)` as you are trying to call here...

```
bool mytest::validate_config(const std::string &s) {
    configFileStream(s.c_str());
    return true;
}
```

If you want to open the file, you can call `open(...)` on it:

```
bool mytest::validate_config(const std::string &s) {
    configFileStream.open(s.c_str());
    return true;
}
```